# ReasonReact.Router implementation and serving static files with Express server

Tags: node.js, express, reason, reason-react

I have implemented routing using the [Routing](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/docs/en/router.html) feature provided in ReasonReact. It looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/schinns/c511f32aafe147cc23bc8eea3309cf77). It works great, until I have it being served by a node.js express server. It will still route, but when I refresh I get for example `cannot GET /about`. Seems like the server is trying to serve a directory or file that doesn't exist. I have tried to change the mountpath from `"/"` to `"*"`, but to no avail.

Anyone have an idea how to get routing working on a ReasonReact app being served by a Node.js Express server?

Here is what my server looks like:

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//serve static files
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "..", "my-reason-react-app", "public")));
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "my-reason-react-app", "public", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: I think the catch-all route is `/*`

Comment: I tried that as well!

Answer (score 0):

The way the express app is serving the static files is the problem. The easiest solution to fixing the problem was having the server in the same directory as the client.